# Unsupported operand type Python when combine multiple range funtions inside a variable

Tags: python

I got this from github and want to analyse it for a project I am doing. I believe it was coded before Python3 was released. I am a newbie at coding and have managed to correct some of the earlier syntax errors. I would appreciate some expert help. Thanks.

So this is my code that I am using. When I run it I get the following error:

```
Generate HTTP Test Files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./http/generator.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "./http/generator.py", line 33, in main
    sizes = range(1, 10, 1) + range(10, 100, 10) + range(100, 1000, 100)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'
```

Thanks for any input guys.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import string
import random
import os
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description="Generate HTTP Test Files")
parser.add_argument('--dir', '-d',
                    dest="dir",
                    action="store",
                    help="Directory to store outputs",
                    default="results",
                    required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
DIR = args.dir
PACKAGE_SIZE = 1500

# Generate a random string
# SIZE is number of characters to generate
# CHARS is the range of characters to select from
def rand_string(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

def main():
  print ("Generate HTTP Test Files")
  # Create output directory
  if not os.path.exists(DIR):
    os.makedirs(DIR)

  # Specify the sizes of files to generate (number of packages)
  sizes = range(1, 10, 1) + range(10, 100, 10) + range(100, 1000, 100)
   
  # Randomly generate ASCII characters for the specified sizes
  for size in sizes:
    filename = "%s/%s_Packages" % (DIR, size)
    outfile = open(filename, "w")
    outfile.write(rand_string(size * PACKAGE_SIZE))
    outfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2, `range` returned a list. You can add lists together to concatenate them.

In Python 3, `range` returns a special range object. These cannot be added. But you can easily convert a range to a list.

```
sizes = list(range(1, 10, 1)) + list(range(10, 100, 10)) + list(range(100, 1000, 100))
```